# Incompatible types required

Tags: java, android, lambda, rx-android

I have that code (not mine):

```
private static class RxCallAdapterWrapper implements CallAdapter<Observable<?>> {
    private final CallAdapter<?> wrapped;
    @Override
    public <R> Observable<?> adapt(Call<R> call) {
        Observable<?> observableWrapped = (Observable<?>) wrapped.adapt(call);
        return observableWrapped.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {

            if (notHasNetworkConnection()) {
                return Observable.error(new NoConnectionException());// Here happens the error
            }

            return Observable.error(throwable);
        });
    }
.... Other code
}
```

When I try to compile in Android Studio I get the following error:

```
Error:(56, 44) error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda
expression Observable<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Observable<?
extends CAP#1> where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable: CAP#1 extends
Object from capture of ? extends Object
```

Environment:
AS 3.0.1
API (Compile, Target): 27.0.0
Java compatibility: 1.8
RXJava: 1.1.1
RxAndroid: 1.1.0

What I have to typecast/return to satisfy the lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that each occurrence of the `?` is potentially a different type. So for example:

```
List<?> list1 = ...;
List<?> list2 = ...;

list1.addAll(list2);
```

Would fail in the addAll operation because that line must compile regardless of the actual element times of of list1 or list2 and There is a "infinite" number of combos that won't work (eg. `List<String> list1 ... List<Double> list2`).

What you need to do here is to use type parameters to bound to the same type those `?` that actually represent the same type (or perhaps one is a super or child of the other:

```
private static class RxCallAdapterWrapper<T> implements CallAdapter<Observable<T>> {
    private final CallAdapter<T> wrapped;
    @Override
    public <R> Observable<T> adapt(Call<R> call) {
        Observable<T> observableWrapped = wrapped.adapt(call);
        return observableWrapped.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {

            if (notHasNetworkConnection()) {
                return Observable.error(new NoConnectionException());// Here happens the error
            }

            return Observable.error(throwable);
        });
    }
.... Other code
}
```

Here I'm making the assumption that the intention is for all the `?` to be the same type which is now represented by the type parameter `T`. However that might not be the case. Please let me know if so and what is failing and we can work out a more accurate answer.